# Make [eu] a synonym of [european-union]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

In a political context [eu](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) is synonymous with the European Union (which uses [european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union)).

**Request:** Can [eu](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) be made a synonym of [european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems reasonable. I've done it.